# how to join ts files together into mp4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, codec

I download a lot of streams since the internet speed is too slow to watch high definition. When I download a stream I find the .m3u8 file which points to the TS files. Then I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i stream.m3u8 vid.mp4
```

This works. But it takes a really long time because it basically reëncodes everything, even though it's already the right format. To avoid reëncoding I can use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i stream.m3u8 -vcodec copy -acodec copy vid.mp4
```

This works fine when I play from start to end without interuption. But When I skip back or forward, vlc has trouble creating an image. It can't properly display for a few seconds. This is very annoying.

My question: **How Can I create the video without complete reëncoding, but WITH good vlc rendering at any point?**

Comment: Do you specifically need the MP4 container format? Please show the complete console output from your second command.

Comment: I do not specifically need the mp4 container. An MKV would siffice. That doesnt get rid of the problem though

Answer (score 4):

You're asking ffmpeg to encode the files into mp4 instead joining them into a single stream. You need to [concatenate](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) into `temp.ts` and then convert that into `.mp4` with `-codec copy`.

Also, I believe you need to convert `adts` to `aac` in the second step `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc`.

Comment: I tried this and the result is not satisfying. The audio never had any problems in the MKV format, just the video stream had hiccups. And with this, I get the same while having to perform three seperate steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not re-encode, you might not be able to change the key frames etc of the video, resulting to the behavior you describe.

You could try however something like:

```
ffmpeg -i stream.m3u8 -codec:v "libx264" "-preset" "ultrafast" output.mp4
```

Keep in mind that what you gain in speed you lose in quality, so "fast" might be better...

Answer (score 0):

See my variant with ffmpeg
[mp4joiner](https://github.com/bogdik/mp4joiner)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It might be worth adding a little more than a screenshot - [here's a guide on how to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). I also noticed your username and the name on the github account is the same  - revealing your affliation to the software is necessary,